# Why does the behavior of magit's pull operations differ?

Tags: magit

The story here is that I use `magit` at work, where our workflow involves the use of a preposterous number of branches on our central remote (used for various purposes, but most notably as part of our deploy and manual testing processes). For my local development purposes, I have no need to stay up-to-date on most of these extraneous references. Before adopting `magit`, when using git porcelain I'd generally use specific `pull` and `fetch` commands, both to save time and to leave my repo un-cluttered. Whenever I wanted to update `master`, for instance, I'd usually use

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -
```

When I adopted `magit`, I was initially puzzled by how long pulling (using  `magit-pull-from-upstream`) would take. As time went on I eventually discovered (using the `magit-process` buffer) that `magit` was using the command `git pull origin` to update my `master` branch. That command, in addition to updating master, fetches every remote branch under the sun (which is  lot of pointless references I don't need, remember).

I've solved this issue for myself (i.e. I'm not looking for a solution here) by switching to using `magit-pull-from-pushremote` instead, after configuring the push-to remote. That, evidently, uses `git pull origin master` (as I expected I'd get from the other command).

I'm looking for an explanation for the different behavior of these two commands. Why would one yield `git pull origin` and one yield `git pull origin master`? Why wouldn't both do the (in my opinion objectively more useful) `git pull origin master`?

Comment: "Why wouldn't both do the (in my opinion objectively more useful) `git pull origin master`?" - Of course if it was this way someone would ask "where is the objectively more useful `git pull origin` command, why do I have to pull each branch individually?"

Comment: I sometimes have lots of branches which I don't want to keep up to date. I just pulled them once, had a look and forgot about them. So I don't want to pull the latest changes from all these. I'm only interested in maste. I like a lot that I have control. I can choose to update one or multiple branches, depending on my needs.

Comment: @npostavs I know that I expressed an opinion, and that others may feel otherwise. I don't need you to tell me that that aspect of my question isn't completely objective.

Ultimately the reason I asked the question is because `magit-pull-from-upstream` is the more natural first choice, so in a sense its behavior is more relevant. There doesn't appear to be a way to configure that function to use my command, which seems backwards to me.

Additionally, I tried to provide context as to why I _don't_ want to `fetch` branches I don't explicitly list. I understand that's not everyone's situation.

Comment: Well I think only tarsius can answer the question definitively because he wrote the code, but he's [on vacation till August](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2699). Perhaps it was just simple oversight; I see that both `magit-fetch-from-{upstream,pushremote}` do `git fetch <remote>` without giving a branch.

Comment: @caisah Another way to restrict which branches are pulled is to configure `remote.origin.fetch`.

Answer (score 2):

`magit-pull-from-upstream` does not explicitly specify the remote branch because if we did that, then tags that point to commits that are being pulled would not be pulled along with the branch (i.e. the commits and the branch ref).

For a while (`2.?` to `2.6.2`) the remote branch was explicitly specified for safety reasons, but I went back to not specifying the remote branch after a user pointed out the above issue.

`magit-pull-from-pushremote` does specify the remote branch because in that case it has to be specified or it might pull from `branch.NAME.merge` (i.e. the upstream) instead of the branch "with the same name as the local branch".

---

To limit what branches are being pulled by git's dwim pull command (`git pull` or `git pull REMOTE`) and by extension `magit-pull-from-upstream`, configure `remote.NAME.fetch`.